# Jooq Problem with Enums and different databases

Tags: sql, postgresql, h2, jooq

i am using jooq and i am trying to use a `punishment` enum, but when i try to do an insert statement, i get the following:

```java
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [insert into "punishments" ("userId", "guildId", "punishment", "startData", "expired", "reason", "operator", "id", "endData") values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; ERROR: column "punishment" is of type punishment but expression is of type character varying
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
Position: 142
```

## How i generate code

Using Gradle, flyway and jooq plugin i am able to migrate **h2** database and then use jooq on it to generate code.

#### The following is my jooq configuration (it's inside the build.gradle)

```
jooq {
    version = '3.16.5'
    edition = nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqEdition.OSS

    configurations {
        main {
            generateSchemaSourceOnCompilation = true
            generationTool {
                jdbc {
                    driver = 'org.h2.Driver'
                    url = "jdbc:h2:file:${project.buildDir}/migration/h2;MODE=PostgreSQL"
                    user = 'SA'
                    password = ''
                    properties {
                        property {
                            key = 'ssl'
                            value = 'false'
                        }
                    }
                }
                generator {
                    name = 'org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator'
                    database {
                        name = 'org.jooq.meta.h2.H2Database'
                        inputSchema = 'PUBLIC'
                        outputSchema = ''
                    }
                    generate {
                        deprecated = false
                        records = true
                        immutablePojos = true
                        fluentSetters = true
                    }
                    target {
                        packageName = 'me.bluetree242.bbot.jooq'
                    }
                    strategy.name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy'
                    strategy {
                        matchers {
                            tables {
                                table {
                                    tableClass {
                                        transform = "PASCAL"
                                        expression = "\$0_TABLE"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            enums {
                                "enum" {
                                    enumClass {
                                        transform = "PASCAL"
                                        expression = "\$0_ENUM"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### The following is the sql used to create the table and enum

```sql
CREATE TYPE punishment AS ENUM ('MUTE', 'BAN', 'QUARANTINE', 'TIMEOUT', 'KICK');
CREATE TABLE punishments(
    "userId" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "guildId" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "punishment" punishment NOT NULL ,
    "expired" boolean NOT NULL,
    "operator" BIGINT,
    "reason" text,
    "endDate" BIGINT,
    "id" integer,
    "startDate" BIGINT NOT NULL
)
```

#### And this is my code to insert

```java
            jooq.insertInto(PunishmentsTable.PUNISHMENTS)
                    .set(PunishmentsTable.PUNISHMENTS.USERID, userId)
                    .set(PunishmentsTable.PUNISHMENTS.GUILDID, guild.getId())
                    .set(PunishmentsTable.PUNISHMENTS.PUNISHMENT, type.asJooq())
                    .set(PunishmentsTable.PUNISHMENTS.STARTDATA, System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .set(PunishmentsTable.PUNISHMENTS.EXPIRED, !type.isSupportUndo())
                    .set(PunishmentsTable.PUNISHMENTS.REASON, operator.getReasonText(this))
                    .set(PunishmentsTable.PUNISHMENTS.OPERATOR, operator.getAsId())
                    .set(PunishmentsTable.PUNISHMENTS.ID, id)
                    .set(PunishmentsTable.PUNISHMENTS.ENDDATA, duration.toMillis() == 0 ? 0 : System.currentTimeMillis() + duration.toMillis())
                    .execute();
```

### Database Used to run the program

generated with **h2**, uses postgreSQL when running the program

#### When Using postgres to generate the code

If i use postgres to generate the code, everything goes fine, but this isn't an option for me building must not require a database, local must be used (like h2)

Comment: Why can't you use PostgreSQL for code generation? H2 can mimick only a few PG specific features. Why waive all of that goodness? [Note, you can always use testcontainers for code generation](https://blog.jooq.org/using-testcontainers-to-generate-jooq-code/)

Comment: is there a way to do it with h2, but change something in the  config of jooq or something

Comment: H2's enums had tons of bugs in the past. What H2 version are you using?

Comment: version 2.1.210

Comment: but why would a bug in h2 cause issues, i think its just jooq not casting the expression, so postgresql is confused, am i right?

Comment: With all the past enum type related issues in H2, there simply wasn't any incentive in jOOQ to make enum types work better. In 2.1.210, it should probably be possible to achieve PG compatibility though. I'll investigate this next week. Anyway. I really recommend you use testcontainers for code generation, or an actual PG database, if you're using vendor specific stuff. Otherwise, you'll just be chasing these edge cases forever.

Comment: I could fix this issue by stopping using enums, and instead use a check, and jooq forced types for enum object in java, Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that works too, of course, and is probably more maintainable on the DDL side, should you ever need to alter the enum values... Note, you can [answer your own question here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions), explaining your workaround. Might be useful to others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, i had to stop using enums, and use something simmilar. I used a check instead of an enum, and varchar, and finally forced type to use java's enums.

Here is my new query to create the table, of course after purging the old one.

```sql
CREATE TABLE punishments(
    "userId" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "guildId" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "punishmentType" varchar NOT NULL check ("punishmentType" in ('MUTE', 'BAN', 'QUARANTINE', 'TIMEOUT', 'KICK')),
    "expired" boolean NOT NULL,
    "operator" BIGINT,
    "reason" text,
    "endDate" BIGINT,
    "id" integer,
    "startDate" BIGINT NOT NULL
)
```